# async output to rich text box while code is running

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Consider i have a function like below, i want to run the code and after that code has finished running i want to output to my own console (richtextbox) before the next code block.

```
void runThis()
{

    DisplayConsole.print("Starting calculation");

    runCalculation();

    DisplayConsole.print("Searching...");

    search();

    DisplayConsole.print("Perform algorithm");

    algorithm();

    DisplayConsole.print("Finalising");

    finallyThis();
}
```

But what is happening is that DisplayConsole with not print until the entire runthis() function has finish. What i want to do it display print then run the function, and when the function has finish running display the next print.

Answer (score 0):

Use Backgroundworker and report progress to UI thread.

[MSDN Background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)